# How to return an array from a function

Tags: php, arrays, function

I have a function which is suposed to return an array. But it is not working. When i try a print_r nothing is returned. The strange thing is that if I put a print_r in the function  just before the return, it is returning the array properly. Hope someone can help. Thank you in advance for your replies. Cheers. Marc.

```
$url = "http://www.somesite.com";
$path ="somexpath";
$print = print_url_data($url, $path);
print_r($print);

  function print_url_data($url, $path)
{
     $content = get_url_data($url, $path);
     foreach ($content as $value)
     {
          $output .= $value->nodeValue . "<br />";
     }
     return $output;
}

function get_url_data($url, $path)
{
     $xml_content = get_url($url);
     $dom = new DOMDocument();
     @$dom->loadHTML($xml_content);
     $xpath = new DomXPath($dom);
     $content_title = $xpath->query($path);
     $tableau = array();
     foreach ($content_title as $node) 
        array_push($tableau, utf8_decode(urldecode($node->nodeValue)));


     return $tableau; //What is being returned to the function call
}

function get_url($url)
{
  $curl = curl_init();

  // Setup headers - I used the same headers from Firefox version 2.0.0.6
  // below was split up because php.net said the line was too long. :/
  $header[0] = "Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,";
  $header[0] .= "text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5";
  $header[] = "Cache-Control: max-age=0";
  $header[] = "Connection: keep-alive";
  $header[] = "Keep-Alive: 300";
  $header[] = "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7";
  $header[] = "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5";
  $header[] = "Pragma: "; // browsers keep this blank.

  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Googlebot/2.1 (+http://www.google.com/bot.html)');
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, '[url=http://www.google.com]http://www.google.com[/url]');
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip,deflate');
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);

  $html = curl_exec($curl); // execute the curl command
  curl_close($curl); // close the connection

  return $html; // and finally, return $html
}
```

Comment: Inside of the function, put a `var_dump($tableau);` just before the `return` statement and see what happens.

Comment: try to var_dump the variable from within the fn itself.

Comment: Maybe you mistyped the variable? `$someVariables = myFunction(); print_r($someVariable);`  See how I have an «S» in one of the names?

Comment: Show us where $content_title is defined, else it doesn't exist inside the scope of the function, so $tableau will be an empty array

Comment: I have a feeling `$content_title` is within his `//.... Some Code` section. He mentions that his array outputs properly before the return statement.

Comment: Hello Jack. When putting var_dump() the array is returned but before each value there is this statement: string(value length) . Whiat is that??

Comment: @Marc - That's part of what [`var_dump()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) outputs, namely the type and, in the case of strings, the string length.  So, is the `var_dump` of `$tableau` printing out the correct data?

Comment: yes the data printed out are correct despite the addition of the string value length statement. Is it possible to remove that? If not does, it affect the way I then manipulate the array?

Comment: For those who wanted the full code, it has been added to the post...

Comment: I have no idea who felt the need to downvote the question but I don't think it should be downvoted. The OP has a legitimate problem.

Comment: By the way the suggestion of using var_dump is not helping as it displays the array when var_dump is executed. I would like to be abble to use the array not to display it....

Comment: Glad you got it sorted! Happy coding Marc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry my mistake. I misplaced the array construction. Here below the code that works for those who are interested. Thanks to all that took time trying to help me out. Cheers.

```
<?php

$url = "http://www.somesite.com";
$path = "somexpath";
print_r(print_url_data($url, $path));

///////////////////////////////////


function print_url_data($url, $path)
{
     $content = get_url_data($url, $path);
     $tableau = array();
     foreach ($content as $value)
     {
            array_push($tableau, $value->nodeValue);

     }
     return $tableau;
}



function get_url_data($url, $path)
{
     $xml_content = get_url($url);
     $dom = new DOMDocument();
     @$dom->loadHTML($xml_content);
     $xpath = new DomXPath($dom);
     $content_title = $xpath->query($path);
     return $content_title;
}



function get_url($url)
{
  $curl = curl_init();

  // Setup headers - I used the same headers from Firefox version 2.0.0.6
  // below was split up because php.net said the line was too long. :/
  $header[0] = "Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,";
  $header[0] .= "text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5";
  $header[] = "Cache-Control: max-age=0";
  $header[] = "Connection: keep-alive";
  $header[] = "Keep-Alive: 300";
  $header[] = "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7";
  $header[] = "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5";
  $header[] = "Pragma: "; // browsers keep this blank.

  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Googlebot/2.1 (+http://www.google.com/bot.html)');
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, '[url=http://www.google.com]http://www.google.com[/url]');
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip,deflate');
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);

  $html = curl_exec($curl); // execute the curl command
  curl_close($curl); // close the connection

  return $html; // and finally, return $html
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure errors and warnings are enabled in php.ini file. It may help.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**
With light to the new code that you have posted change :

```
$output .= $value->nodeValue . "<br />";
```

to

```
$output .= $value . "<br />";
```

This working for me if you would like me to post a link to a test script on my server.
(You were referencing $content as an object, but this was declared as an array :] )

---

If by $node->nodeValue you are parsing xml; I had a similar problem with this a while back. I found that explicitly casting the nodevalue to a string when adding it to the array fixed my problem.

I believe this maybe because a reference to the xml object is added to the array instead of the string; once your function ends, the xml object is destroyed and the data is no longer accessible. Hope this helps :)

**Example:**

```
array_push($tableau, (String) utf8_decode(urldecode($node->nodeValue)));
```

Comment: I found out Terry. I misplaced the array construction. Now it is working fine. I created an answer myself. Thank you nevertheless for taking time to help.... Newbie mistake!